# is there OpenNETCF that can work with FrameWork 1.0

Tags: c#, frameworks, windows-mobile

i work with the

```
OpenNETCF.dll
OpenNETCF.Net.dll
```

for get that MAC address from terminal.

i dont have FrameWork 3.5 on this terminal and i dont want to install hem.

is there OpenNETCF that can work with FrameWork 1.0 ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think [Smart Device Framework 1.4](http://www.opennetcf.com/FreeSoftware/SDF1x/tabid/91/Default.aspx) is the last version that worked with .netcf 1.0

In this version, the feature you need can be found at:

```
using OpenNETCF.Net;
...
AdapterInfo[] infos = NetworkAdapter.GetAdaptersInfo()
if (infos != null && infos.Length > 0)
    byte[] macAddr = infos[0].MACAddress;
    ...
```

Comment: You are correct.  Version 1.4 was the last version compatible with CF 1.0, and it's freely available as a download.  Fair warning: there are lots of bugs in it that were fixed in the 2.x builds.

Comment: thanks for the help !, is there OpenNETCF.Net for the Fw1.0
i need to work with OpenNETCF.Net.NetworkInformation for getting the MAC address on windows-mobile that dont have FW3.5